# How to use a defined name in a formula that is referenced in another cell to make it dynamic

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have currently 28 dynamic Defined names I want to use in formula. If I type the name in the formula it works however if I use it in a cell as reference it does not. I'm sure it is just a syntax error.
One of the Defined names is: Bank_1 ='Bank Layout'!$A$2:$A$19.
The values in the defined name is: Where A2 is 260 and goes up to A19 if more numbers needs to be added.

```
    col A
    Bank 01
    260
    261
    262
    263
    264
    265
    266
    267
```

Here is the simple example that work on another sheet.

```
    col A          col B    
    Bank_1     =COUNT(Bank_1)
```

gives me

```
    col A          col B  
    Bank_1          8
```

Then if I use the below it does not work I have tried to put "A1" and "&A1&" to no avail.

```
    col A      col B    
    Bank_1    =COUNT(A1)
```

gives me

```
    col A          col B    
    Bank_1           0
```

I have another formula that sums with the same result.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($M$4:$M$500;Bank_1;$T$4:$T$500))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Gary's Student. It works like a charm.